# Using JUnit to test a method that reverses a singly linked list

Tags: java, testing, junit, linked-list

I'm implementing a singly linked list in Java. I've created a method called *reverseList* which reverses my list, for example:

head -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
Becomes:
head -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null

I've also created a test class (using JUnit) that has a method called *testReverseList* which tests the *reverseList* method. The *insert* method takes the data and also the position in which you want to add a new node. All these three methods seems to be working correctly.

```
public String reverseList() {
    Node prev = null, current = head, next;
    StringBuilder checkList = new StringBuilder();
    while (current != null) {
        checkList.append(current.getData());
        next = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(prev);
        prev = current; 
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;
    return checkList.toString(); 
}

@Test
public void testReverseList() {
    LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
    myList.insert(1, 1);
    myList.insert(2, 2);
    myList.insert(3, 3);
    String normalListOrder = "123";
    assertEquals("Check reverseList, reversing a list with 3 elements.", normalListOrder, myList.reverseList());    
}
```

My question is: I don't believe that I'm properly testing my *reverseList* method by using this approach of appending each data of my node and then returning it, because I'm **not** really checking if it was reversed or not. Furthermore, it looks like it would require more computational resources to do all this. And I don't think that just returning a true at the end of execution would be enough either. So, should I don't test it at all? Is there a better way to do the testing?

**ANSWER:** Thanks everyone. I've followed Pelocho suggestion and overridden the *equals* method and changed my *testReverseList* and *reverseList* methods. I also created *testEquals* method to check the implemented *equals*. It seems that this is the best approach for what I want. All the tests are OK.

```
public LinkedList reverseList() {
    Node prev = null, current = head, next;
    while (current != null) {
        next = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(prev);
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;
    return this;
}

public boolean equals(LinkedList myList) {
    if (myList == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(myList.getListSize() == this.getListSize())) {
        return false;
    }
    // Starts at 1 because retrieveNode pick the position, not index
    for (int i = 1; i != this.getListSize(); i++) {
        if (myList.retrieveNode(i).getData() != this.retrieveNode(i).getData()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Test
public void testReverseList() {
    LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
    myList.insert(1, 1);
    LinkedList singleElementList = new LinkedList();
    singleElementList.insert(1, 1);
    assertEquals("Check reverseList, reversing a list with 1 element.", true, myList.reverseList().equals(singleElementList));  
    LinkedList expectedList = new LinkedList();
    myList.insert(2, 2);
    myList.insert(3, 3);
    expectedList.insert(3, 1);
    expectedList.insert(2, 2);
    expectedList.insert(1, 3);
    assertEquals("Check reverseList, reversing a list with 3 elements.", true, myList.reverseList().equals(expectedList));  
}

public void testEquals() {
    LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
    myList.insert(1, 1);
    assertEquals("Check reverseList, comparing to the same list.", true, myList.reverseList().equals(myList));
    LinkedList myList2 = new LinkedList();
    myList2.insert(1, 1);
    myList2.insert(2, 2);
    assertEquals("Check reverseList, different size list.", false, myList.reverseList().equals(myList2));
}
```

Comment: i guess your question is for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Your assert is verifying that you **didn't** reverse the list. Eg. you're asserting that the order returned by the `reverseList()` method is still the same order as it was originally....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start suggesting to return a new `LinkedList` when reversing it. But that's just for the sake of immutability

Anyway, you want to test your method, right?

Right now you're altering the state and returning a representation of current state just for the sake of testing. Be aware that modifying your production code just to be able to perform tests is not usually a good practice. You're modifying its inner state so *that's what you need to check*

```
@Test
public void testReverseList() {
    LinkedList someList = new LinkedList();
    myList.insert(1, 1);
    myList.insert(2, 2);
    myList.insert(3, 3);

    LinkedList expectedList = new LinkedList();
    // You'll probably want to check these lines in order to ensure I'm using it the right way
    expectedList.insert(3, 1);
    expectedList.insert(2, 2);
    expectedList.insert(1, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < expectedList.size(); i++)
        assertEquals("Checking item with index " + i, myList.get(i), expectedList.get(i));
    assertEquals(myList.size(), expectedList.size());

    // Or even better, implement LinkedList.equals() so you can use
    assertEquals("Check reverseList", myList, expectedList);    
}
```

By performing the check using `toString()` you're relaying too much in its implementation. Let's say you have an Object whose `toString()` method returns a random String (I'm not sure why that could be useful but let's assume that for a minute). `assertEquals(myObject.toString(), myObject.toString())` would probably fail but `assertEquals(myObject, myObject)` would not

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the following changes:

Separate the list reversal from the "toString" representation, and call the methods separately.

Then, make sure you are testing for the correct result (you want "321", right?).

```
public LinkedList reverseList() {
    Node prev = null, current = head, next;
    while (current != null) {
        next = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(prev);
        prev = current; 
        current = next;
    }
    head = current;
    return this;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder checkList = new StringBuilder();
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        checkList.append(current.getData());
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return checkList.toString(); 
}

@Test
public void testReverseList() {
    LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
    myList.insert(1, 1);
    myList.insert(2, 2);
    myList.insert(3, 3);
    String reverseListOrder = "321";
    assertEquals("Check reverseList, reversing a list with 3 elements.", reverseListOrder, myList.reverseList().toString());    
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the @Test annotation - he asks about JUnit, so it is probably worth mentioning that a JUNIT test would be separated and look a bit different!

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard to understand your code. If you need a code review I can begin by telling you never use the same class names as the ones in the API(LinkedList). Then make a separate class and use junit for the tests. Your test fails ? You are comparing "123" with what should be "321" no ? And why does your list has a method that inserts a key value pair ?